# Why didn't she use magic?

Tags: plot-explanation, cursed-2020

In *Cursed* S01E01 we saw that

1. Nimue's magic manifests when threatened (scene in the forest with enchanting a bow)
2. Despite claiming she doesn't control it it seems she can make it do specifically what she wants when she wants it (scene with dice and chair in the tavern)

Both these points become valid when she returns to her village under attack, but she only runs around and doesn't use it and it doesn't trigger by instinct. Not even when her or her mother's lives were threatened

Can there be an in-universe explanation why or is this a big plot hole?